# Why do I get an error if I write @Data and @Builder together when I write Lombok Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, lombok

**Error**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Error attempting to get column 'user_postcode' from result set.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: 06035
; Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: 06035;
```

I ran JUnitTest in Spring Security, and an error occurred when I wrote `@Builder` and `@Data` annotation together. There is no problem when writing an annotation one by one, but an error occurred when writing two together.

Comment: Try replacing `@Data` with `@Getter` `@Setter` and the other data annotations you use (to string or whatever) and see if that fixes it.  `@Builder` may be looking for `@Getter` and `@Setter` but not finding it before `@Data` can decompose into its parts.  (maybe)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use `@Data` on `@Entity` classes. Implementation of `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` can go with conflict with JPA lazy loading.

I assume that you want to benefit from builder pattern for your entities, to do so you should address these rules:

- Don't use `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `@Data` on JPA entities
- Exclude lazy attributes when using `@ToString`
- Add `@NoArgsConstructor` to entities with `@Builder` or `@AllArgsConstructor`.

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Setter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Getter
public class ExampleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String userPostcode;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ExampleEntity entity = (ExampleEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, entity.id) && Objects.equals(userPostcode, entity.userPostcode);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, userPostcode);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExampleEntity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userPostcode='" + userPostcode + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```